# ¿Cómo puedo extraer esta expresión con preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

Tengo este texto extraído, y que ejecuto por comando para extraer los correos electronicos, el tema va en que me retorna el mensaje esta estructura:

```
Modelo:\r\n  
Maule\r\n    

Unidad:\r\n  
28\r\n       

Fecha:\r\n   
26/05/2021\r\
```

Pero como el dato a extraer esta con saltos de linea no me permite ingresar a ese dato.

Normalmente los extraia asi:

```
preg_match('/Modelo:(.*)/',$correo,$model);
```

Pero si ocupo el que utilizo normalmente no me lo marca

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces como podría hacer que la expresion regular me tome los \r\n que me agrego al transformarlo a texto puro?

Comment: No se entiende. Un texto ¿que ejecutas?, los textos no se ejecutan. Para extraer correos electrónicos, no veo ningún correo electrónico. Dato a eliminar ¿cuál es el dato a eliminar? ¿debajo de qué?.

Comment: Es un comando que captura el email y extraigo y convierto el HTML en solo texto, lo que me devuelve la consola es eso que esta en 1, 2 o 3 y necesito extraer por ejemplo lo que esta después de Modelo, Unidad y fecha @Sal más que nada algo con expresiones regulares que me permita extraer la info que me retorna

Comment: Esos caracteres \r y \n implican salto de linea y no son visibles. En tu caso te los devuelve asi visibles como un string cualquiera?

Comment: Osea al momento de extraer Modelo, me lo extrae nulo y yo lo que quiero en ese caso es extraer la palabra Maule, lo que diche Fecha que em extraiga la fecha pero donde esta con saltos de linea no me deja capturar la palabra

Comment: prueba con `str_replace`

Answer (score 1):

Si el formato del texto es el siguiente:

```
Modelo:\r\n  
Maule\r\n    
Unidad:\r\n  
28\r\n       
Fecha:\r\n   
26/05/2021\r\
```

Entonces, para encontrar el *"Modelo"* podemos modificar la `RegEx` así:

```
/Modelo:\s*(\S+)/
```

Donde:

- `Modelo:`: Buscamos la frase exacta
- `\s*`: Seguida de cero o mas caracter de espacio en blanco, incluido el espacio, tabulación, avance de página, avance de línea y otros espacios Unicode.
- `\S+`: Seguido de uno o mas caracter que no sea un espacio en blanco.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$correo = "
Modelo:\r\n  
Maule\r\n    
Unidad:\r\n  
28\r\n       
Fecha:\r\n   
26/05/2021\r";

preg_match('/Modelo:\s*(\S+)/', $correo, $matches);
$model = $matches[1]."\n";

preg_match('/Fecha:\s*(\S+)/', $correo, $matches);
$date = $matches[1]."\n";
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e42f5d17cff301399403ab26c7048845006b2cf7)</kbd>